# Jsoup get dynamically generated HTML

Tags: java, javascript, parsing, jsoup

I can connect to most sites and get the HTML just fine but when trying to connect to a website where most of the content is generated after the initial page load with JavaScript, it does not get any of that data. Is there any way to do this with Jsoup or does it not support it?

Comment: JSoup is parser, not browser engine. You would need to use some web driver, like [selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/)

Answer (score 5):

JSoup has some basic connection handling included, but it is not a web browser. It excels at parsing static html content. It does not run any javascript, so you are out of luck. However, there are different options that you might follow:

1. You can analyze the page that you want to retrieve and find out how the content you are interested in gets loaded. Often it is not very hard to tap the original source of the loaded content and work with this. This approach has the benefit that you get what you want with no need of extra libraries and the retrieval will be fast.
2. You can use a (full) browser and automate the loading of the page. A very good tool for this is [selenium webdriver](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/) in combination with the headless webkit browser [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/). This however requires extra software and extra libraries in your project and will run much much slower than the first solution.