# jSoup get data using td-class tags from webpage

Tags: java, jsoup

I would like to get data from http://www.futbol24.com/Live/?__igp=1&LiveDate=20141104 using jSoup. I know how to use jSoup - but I am finding it difficult to pinpoint the data that I need.

I would like the Time, Home Team and Away Team from each row of the tbody table. So the output from the first row should be:

```
08:30     Persipura Jayapura      Pelita Bandung Raya
```

I can see the td class of each of these elements as "status alt", "home" and "guest".

Currently I have tried the below, but it doesn't seem to output anything... what am I doing wrong?

```
        matches = new ArrayList<Match>();

             //getHistory
            String website = "http://www.futbol24.com/Live/?__igp=1&LiveDate=20141104";
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(website).get();

            Element tblHeader = doc.select("tbody").first();
            List<Match> data = new ArrayList<>();
            for (Element element1 : tblHeader.children()){

                Match match = new Match();
                match.setTimeOfMatch(element1.select("td.status.alt").text());
                match.setAwayTeam(element1.select("td.home").text());
                match.setHomeTeam(element1.select("td.guest").text());

                data.add(match);
                System.out.println(data.toString());
```

Does anybody know how I can use jSoup to get these elements from each row of the table?

Thanks,

Rob

Comment: I suspect that this content is generated by JavaScript dynamically after page will be loaded. If that is the case then you will not be able to use Jsoup here because it is parser, not browser emulator. You would need web-driver like selenium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content of this site is generated via AJAX it seems. Jsoup can't handle this, since it is not a browser that interprets JavaScript. To solve this scraping problem you may need something like [Selenium webdriver](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp). I gave a longer answer to a generalized question about this before, so please look here:

[Jsoup get dynamically generated HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22390741/jsoup-get-dynamically-generated-html/22400976#22400976)

Comment: So when I use Selenium to load the webpage, could I then use jSoup on the result? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes, you can do that, if you want. Just use the driver.getPageSource() method from selenium to get the html. Of courese you can also use selenium methods directly, but if the site reloads very fast you might get StaleElementExceptions

Comment: Ahh... and don't forget to upvote and maybe accept the answer if you feel helped by it.