# Jsoup.connect(url).get() doesn't give me the full source code in Android

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I'm trying to get full source-code from a website in Android, but it stops in the middle.
I have two webpages, with the same contents (it's a shows site, different performers) and I can't figure out why it's not working with the other performer.
This is the webpage which I can't get the full source code:
[First Performer](http://view-source:https://www.zappa-club.co.il/%D7%AA%D7%92%D7%99%D7%95%D7%AA/%D7%92%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9F-%D7%91%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%93%D7%95/)

I'm using:

```
String url = "https://www.zappa-club.co.il/%D7%AA%D7%92%D7%99%D7%95%D7%AA/%D7%92%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9F-%D7%91%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%93%D7%95/"  
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jsoup get dynamically generated HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22390741/jsoup-get-dynamically-generated-html)

Comment: Most likely dynamically generated content (js, etc.). For Android: use a webview to grab the rendered html source, then parse with jsoup (compare this example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39140121/android-parse-js-generated-urls-with-jsoup/39174441#39174441).