# I need take data this site but fail

Tags: curl, jsoup, httpclient

I login site and return this site and take data frompage  source code but nothing .
I try php cURL, Jsoup, HttpClient but nothing.
But one taked way rigth Click and checks on chrome
I need this div and class in data please help me!
Thanks.
[image]

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused. You want to get the value of this "`sensor-value`" from the page's source code? And it only shows up in the page when it's displayed in chrome, it's not in the page's source code?

Comment: Please post code as code, not as a screen shot. Maybe you could include the source code you have tried also.

Comment: @Cliabhach Yes, just like you said.

Comment: @Tomas By Ok Thanks.

Comment: http://deatherapps.com/apps/sgr/source-code.txt

Comment: http://deatherapps.com/apps/sgr/chrome-code.txt

Comment: I think this scripte is affecting                                                            
<script type="text/javascript" src="/patient/dtagent_ICASTVdegijovx_7000000071013.js" data-dtconfig="agentUri=/patient/dtagent_ICASTVdegijovx_7000000071013.js|rid=RID_1922813512|rpid=251699052|lastModification=1508014918362|tp=500,50,0|lab=1|reportUrl=dynaTraceMonitor|app=carelink.minimed.eu|domain=minimed.eu"></script>

Comment: http://deatherapps.com/apps/sgr/once.png

Comment: @DeAtHeR - WHat Thomas meant was that you should include all relevant information directly in your question. Links to external files should be kept to the absolute minimum. Code can be placed directly in text form in the question. That is what you should do. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jsoup get dynamically generated HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22390741/jsoup-get-dynamically-generated-html)