# How can I Access html using Jsoup from modern website?

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup

I'm trying to scrape information for a house on the [website(ex price)](https://www.realtor.ca/real-estate/19963675/3-1-bedroom-single-family-house-213-heritage-lake-bv-heritage-pointe). I'm using Jsoup.

I'm not to sure what the output means...

I don't get any output when I try to print the price. so I used `document.outerHtml()` just to see what would come up (see below).

My code:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws  Exception{
        
        final Document document = Jsoup.connect("https://www.realtor.ca/real-estate/19963675/3-1-bedroom-single-family-house-213-heritage-lake-bv-heritage-pointe").get();
        

        Elements elements = document.select("div.leftTableCell");


        for(Element row : elements){

            System.out.println(row.text());
        }



        System.out.println(document.outerHtml());

       
    }
```

Output:

[image]

expected: $750,000

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jsoup get dynamically generated HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22390741/jsoup-get-dynamically-generated-html)

Comment: I tried to hit the link, but getting following msg,The listing you are looking for no longer exists.