# JSoup doesn't have opened tags

Tags: java, html, dom, jsoup

I had a lot of fun using JSoup recently, unfortunately it doesn't work as I thought. When parsing the webpage, the page did not have some HTML tags open. Here is my code (very simple):

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://osu.ppy.sh/beatmapsets/591255#osu/1264233").get();
        System.out.println(doc);
    }
```

All I want to get from this webpage is the `Points of Failure` graph localized at bottom-right. The thing is I cannot access these tags' childrens because they are closed like this:

```html
<div class="js-react--beatmapset-page osu-layout osu-layout--full"></div>
```

Code showing this:

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://osu.ppy.sh/beatmapsets/382400#osu/1001682").get();
        Elements elements = doc.getElementsByClass("js-react--beatmapset-page osu-layout osu-layout--full");
        System.out.println(elements);
    }
```

I also tried to download the whole webpage and save it to the `.html` file using code from this site: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/download-web-page-using-java/, but it also had closed tags in the same spots.

I searched the internet for solutions but it all failed so my last resort is to post here.

All I need is to download `.html` file from the webpage and get data value from it.
Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Keep in mind that many webpages don't simply return HTML (like this one). Look in your network tab when you access the site. See all that? JSoup doesn't do that; it returns the HTML from the URL, and that's it. If you want to interact with a web page like your'e a browser you'll need to run, e.g., a headless browser (or a headful one) and play timing games or wait for specific elements to render etc.

Comment: maybe this answer can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22390741/jsoup-get-dynamically-generated-html/22400976#22400976